# Chaining Requests in Restify

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm have the following code which isn't working:

```
var server = restify.createServer( ... );
server
  .get('/', function(req,res,next){ res.send('server is up and listening'); })
  .get('/test', function(req,res,next){ res.send('test route'); })
;
```

Chaining like it's shown above works for me in express. I'd like to know how to achieve same with restify since it makes my code look cleaner.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible unfortunately.

However in my opinion, it's much nice than being the full thing:

```
var server = restify.createServer( ... );

server
  .get('/', function(req,res,next){ res.send('server is up and listening'); })
  .get('/test', function(req,res,next){ res.send('test route'); })
;

server.get('/', function(req,res,next){ res.send('server is up and listening'); })
server.get('/test', function(req,res,next){ res.send('test route'); })
```

This is a pretty trivial example of course.